# get auto approved hits from amazon mturk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using gem `ruby-aws`. I create hits and manually accept or reject the assignments or wait for mturk to auto-approve the hits. Now, I want to get those hits that are auto-approved by amazon mechanical turk. Is there any way I can do it? I hope my question is clear. I  checked the [Amazon Mturk documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/) but could not find anything, am I missing something here?

Comment: I could use NumberofAssignmentsCompleted but that would return all those assignments that I have manually accepted or rejected too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HITs aren't auto-approved, only assignments, although the assignment autoapproval is often triggered on consensus being reached within a HIT.  It also is triggered after a certain period of time if you haven't manually accepted or rejected an assignment.

If you want to distinguish between assignments you've approved and assignments that were auto-approved by Amazon, you could put something in the RequesterFeedback when you do the approval, e.g. Approved by SG, then ignore those assignments.

Finally, you could check the ApprovalTime and the AutoApprovalTime, and if they are the same, then you know that it was very likely done by Amazon and not by you.